# Metric to mesure the span of a set of vectors

Tags: python, data-science, metrics

I want to find a good metric to mesure how big is the span of a set of vectors.

More practically: I'm encoding some words with a 100 dimensions word embedding and I want to measure how much their vectorial representations span in space. This is meant to be a vocabulary "diversity" metric.

For example:

```
span(["computer","code","data"]) < span(["burger","politics","hamster"])
```

Comment: How do you define the `span`? Total number of characters?

Comment: No, i meant how vectors much they span in space (you can forget the words it was just an example). Maybe by mesuring distances within the set of vectors ? For example the metric should results span([0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]) > span([0,1,1],[0,1.1,0.9], [0,0.9,1.1])

Comment: What you want is a bit subjective, there could be many metrics, not necessarily giving the same order of "span". What are you **really** trying to achieve?

Comment: I would start here: https://towardsdatascience.com/similarity-metrics-in-nlp-acc0777e234c Since they're word embeddings that article is going to provide you the detail you're looking for I suspect.

Comment: As indicated in [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") the a Good Question requires:  
- A title that summarizes the specific problem  
- An Introduction to your problem which provides the context of your problem and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.    
- The simplest data and code which reproduces your problem in a form that a respondent can copy and paste into their environment.  
- reserve images things that are otherwise impossible to describe accurately via text.